# TFS upgrade from 2012 to 2013 - Time to complete guestimate

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are planning on upgrading Team Foundation Server from 2012 to 2015.  I read that in some scenarios it may be better to upgrade first to 2013.  I know the upgrade to 2015 requires significant changes to the DB schema, hence the upgrade process can take a long time.  However I don't know how to compare this to 2013.

How can I guesstimate the time it will take to upgrade from 2012 to 2013.  I am not asking for an very accurate estimate, more of a range (i.e. for a 40GB database allow 1 hour, 1 day, 3 days or 1 week).

Comment: I recently completed a 2008 -> 2012 -> 2015 upgrade. I practised it several times on copies of the system. And that's the only sane way to do this - practice on non-live copies. Is your 40GB a single check-in of your entire code base or years of work-items across the entire TFS product?

Comment: 40GB represents years of work including code, work items, builds etc, We were planning on implementing a trial run like you did, glad you mentioned that.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from my previous comment - you'll only work out the timings by trying it yourself on your own upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I got you. Anecdotally though, how big was your database and about how long did the upgrade to 2015 from 2012 take?

Answer (score 2):

We updated from 2010 to 2015 last fall.  We had almost a terabyte of data over a dozen team project collections and it took around 12 hours to complete the migration.

We considered migrating to each version but in the end decided the 2010 to 2015 migration was support and we could save a ton of time.

FYI - Here is a blog post with some details specifically around the migration of CodedUI test:

https://dotnetcatch.com/2015/10/01/tfs-2010-to-2015-upgrade-codedui-feature-test-builds/